# How do I get the (h, w) value of pixel from the RGB values of the image?

Tags: python, search, location, rgb, pixel

The RGB value can be obtained using the (h, w) value of pixel,

but I am curious how to get the opposite case.

For example, this is how to find the RGB value as (h,w) of pixel.

```
>> img = cv2.imread('Hi.PNG')

>> print(img[50, 50])

[80 80 80]
```

In this case, the RGB value of the pixel corresponding to the (50,50) position of the img is [80 80 80].

**Conversely, I am curious how to output the (h,w) of img corresponding to the RGB value [80 80 80].**

***I tried the method using np.where() and also tried the method of searching using the double for loop, but the desired output did not come out.

I show you the code I tried.

> **1. using np.where()**

```
>> img = cv2.imread('Hi.PNG')

>> lst = np.where((img > [70, 70, 70]) & (img < [98, 98, 98]))

>> print(lst)

(array([111, 111, 111, ..., 242, 242, 242], dtype=int64), array([123, 123, 124, ..., 135, 135, 135], dtype=int64), array([0, 2, 0, ..., 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

I want the RGB values between [70, 70, 70] to [98, 98, 98].

So, I tried using np.where(), and the result was different from the expected result.

**Because I was expecting an array of (h,w) values of pixels.** (When I unpacked the array with tolist() and checked it, the values were indiscriminately included.)

> **2. using the double for loop**

```
>> pos = []
>> for i in range(0, len(img)):
...    for j in range(0, len(img[0])):
...         if img[i, j] > [70, 70, 70] and img[i, j] < [98, 98, 98]:
...             pos.append((i,j))
```

This method throws an error.

**ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

Thank you for your good feedback.

Comment: `(***I tried the method using np.where() and also tried the method of searching using the double for loop, but the desired output did not come out...) ` well these two seem a good first approach, maybe the idea is correct but the code is wrong, please show us what you tried.

Comment: It probably didn't come out because you are using a **lossy** JPEG format, where pixels don't necessarily retain their exact values when saved. Try using **lossless** PNG format.

Comment: Keep in mind that many pixels may have the same RGB value. You only have one RGB value [x y z] from one particular (h, w) value of pixel position, but there maybe mutiple values of (h, w) when searching from RGB.

Comment: Try using: `c_idx, r_idx = np.where(np.all(img == (80, 80, 80), 2))`. The output is two arrays: Array of rows indexes and array of columns indexes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Fra93 Edited and uploaded again. Thank you for your good feedback!

Comment: @TheLongNguyen I got it. That's the way I wanted it. :)

Comment: @Rotem Thanks for the feedback. Is it possible to use np.all() even in the range [70 70 70] < img < [98 98 98]?

Comment: Try the following syntax: `c_idx, r_idx = np.where(np.all((img > [70, 70, 70]) & (img < [98, 98, 98]), 2))`. `img` is a NumPy array, and we can't use the syntax `[70 70 70] < img < [98 98 98]` for NumPy arrays.